# One-To-Many Variables from scraped data

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, rvest

I'm trying to extract data from a website. The script that I'm using is as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(sqldf)

cb_url <- paste0("https://247sports.com/Season/2022-Football/TargetPredictions/?Page=24")

cb_team_gather <- map_df(cb_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
                                html_nodes(".prediction img, .icon-zero") %>%
                                html_attr('alt') %>%
                                str_trim %>% 
                                str_split("   ") %>% 
                                matrix(ncol = 1, byrow = T) %>% 
                                as.data.frame)
```

If you run that exact script, notice it returns 51 observations. **I am trying to get it to produce 50 observations with each page.** The reason I chose this specific page, `?Page=24`, is because it contains an example of the edge case I'm trying to work around.

You will notice that *most* items on this page looks as follows:
[image]

Just one affiliated image. Those variables show up as rows 12 and 13 in the dataframe created with the script above. The edge case is variables like this one:

[image]

Notice in this instance, there are two affiliated images whose `html_attr` I'm trying to extract. This shows up in rows 14 and 15 for in the dataframe created from the script above. The problem is, the only data I need comes from the second image in that screenshot (which in this example, would be `Texas A&M`, the `Oklahoma State` one is not relevant). This is causing there to be 51 observations instead of 50.

I'm going to be running this as part of a larger function, so I won't have any idea as to when these types of edge cases are going to show up, but they will.

Comment: Do note that the 31st player, Mr. 
Marquis Groves-Killebrew, has no University img node at all. Will that be a problem for your code/goals?

Comment: Well that's written into the script. That's why I have `.icon-zero` in the `html_nodes` statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an alternative.  This solution finds the 50 first choice schools and then looks for any flipped choices and then merges the two lists together.

```
page <- read_html(cb_url)

mainschools <-page %>% html_nodes("li.target") %>%
   html_node(".prediction img, .icon-zero") %>%
   html_attr('alt') %>% str_trim 

flippedschools <- page %>% html_nodes("li.target") %>%
   html_node("div.flipped-wrap img") %>% 
   html_attr('alt') %>%  str_trim

flipped <- which(!is.na(flippedschools))

mainschools[flipped] <- flippedschools[flipped]
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your CSS selector is picking both the "old" and "new" team's image nodes. In this solution, I am leveraging a first xpath to exclude those img nodes with `@class = "old"`, and a second xpath that makes sure to capture `span[@class = 'icon-zero']`

```
cb_team_gather <- 
  map_df(cb_url, ~.x %>% read_html %>%
           html_nodes(xpath = "//li[@class = 'prediction']/div//img[not(@class = 'old')]|//li[@class = 'prediction']/div/span[@class = 'icon-zero']") %>%
           html_attr('alt') %>%
           str_trim %>% 
           str_split("   ") %>% 
           matrix(ncol = 1, byrow = T) %>% 
           as.data.frame)

                  V1
1            Georgia
2               Iowa
3           NC State
4          Texas A&M
5  Mississippi State
...
30        Penn State
31                NA
32          Arkansas
...
```

Comment: This is almost correct, but two things. 1) I accidentally put `ncol = 2` in the original post. It actually should be `ncol = 1`. This is still resulting in 49 observations. I think it's because you left out the `.icon-zero` part from the original post.